# Silverlight 3 hosting

Tags: silverlight

I'm a bit confused about hosting Silverlight apps.

On one hand I see that I can host the silverlight app on a [linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471139/are-there-any-gotchas-for-hosting-a-silverlight-app-on-a-linux-server) just defining the mime type, on the other I see some hosting sites saying they are silverlight compatible.

And I also want to play around with the "out of browser" funcionality of silverlight 3. What do I need to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Silverlight needs in order to be hosted on a server is the XAP file and the mime type set.  Thats it.  If you want your app to work "out of browser", there is nothing specific that your server needs to support either.

If you want that Silverlight app to talk to your WCF service or be hosted in an ASP page, you need those services hosted in IIS... but Silverlight, itself is just a single binary file for its distribution, which can be hosted on any site with the mime type.

Marketing buzz words beyond that.

Comment: Right on the money! Marketing buzz words from the hosting services. Just saw: http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T45F Starting to understand sl3 better.

Answer (score 2):

[See here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-whats-new-a-guide.aspx) for a nice overview of the new features in Silverlight 3. In particular you may want to look at the Out of Browser and Offline functions.

You don't need any particular tools to use Silverlight 3 out of browser, all you need to do is to call the `Application.Current.Detach()` method to detach the application.

Hosting of Silverlight applications can be done in any HTML page using the object-tag. So hosting it on a Linux server should work just fine. [See here for an overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089(VS.95).aspx) (msdn).

Answer (score 0):

"silverlight compatible" I would assume just means that they have the MIME entry in place, and it's mainly marketing.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to host microsoft product is by using hosting that runs with Windows OS, then you can deploy it under IIS and set the MIME. You should able to find the recommended hosting provider with windows OS by googling